# Windows 7 Folder Options Annoyance: Icons/Images locked into place -

Tags: windows-7

Just upgraded to Windows 7 issue:

With Vista I had a folder full of pictures (image files of pics) and I could open the folder, click and drag any item and re-arrange it in a free-form manner.  I could take 10 pictures and group them together, move one at a time, etc.

With Windows 7 when I try to move one of the images inside the folde, they are locked in place.  I can click the icon/item, drag it over to a new location, but it reverts back to its original location.  Can someone please help me fix this?  Is it in folder options somewhere?

This should be an easy fix but I am a Mac user and this is the first time I am using windows 7 to help a friend.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the folder window there should be something like "View Options" or "Folder Options", look for 'arrange icons', within that, you'll likely find 'auto arrange' is selected, which will force the icons into some pattern, usually determined by the options just above that... sort by name, date, type, size, etc..

Unselect "Auto Arrange"... all should be good.